# SQL query for searching in the tree

Tags: sql, oracle, search, tree

I have a simple tree that has 4 level of deep data. Here is the table DDL

```
CREATE TABLE HIER_DEMO(
   ID        NUMBER,
   LABEL     VARCHAR2 (100),
   PARENT_ID NUMBER)
```

Hierarchy starts `WITH ID = PARENT_ID`. Number of levels are fixed. It is always 4. We have leafs to all branches at 4th level. So we can also add 3 more columns that represent LABEL of ancestors if necessary.

I need to build a query that

1. Searches for particular phrase in LABEL on any level of hierarchy. For example `LABEL LIKE '%MAGIC_WORD%'`.
2. Returns all the nodes till leaf level under the hierarchy node that satisfies condition 1.
3. In addition we need to return all the ancestors of the hierarchy node that satisfies condition 1.

Here is an example

```
INSERT INTO HIER_DEMO VALUES (1, 'Mike', 1);
INSERT INTO HIER_DEMO VALUES (2, 'Arthur', 2);
INSERT INTO HIER_DEMO VALUES (3, 'Alex', 1);
INSERT INTO HIER_DEMO VALUES (4, 'Suzanne', 1);
INSERT INTO HIER_DEMO VALUES (5, 'Brian', 3);
INSERT INTO HIER_DEMO VALUES (6, 'Rick', 3);
INSERT INTO HIER_DEMO VALUES (7, 'Patrick', 4);
INSERT INTO HIER_DEMO VALUES (8, 'Simone', 4);
INSERT INTO HIER_DEMO VALUES (9, 'Tim', 5);
INSERT INTO HIER_DEMO VALUES (10, 'Andrew', 5);
INSERT INTO HIER_DEMO VALUES (11, 'Sandy', 6);
INSERT INTO HIER_DEMO VALUES (12, 'Brian', 6);
INSERT INTO HIER_DEMO VALUES (13, 'Chris', 7);
INSERT INTO HIER_DEMO VALUES (14, 'Laure', 7);
INSERT INTO HIER_DEMO VALUES (15, 'Maureen', 8);
INSERT INTO HIER_DEMO VALUES (16, 'Andy', 8);
INSERT INTO HIER_DEMO VALUES (17, 'Al', 2);
INSERT INTO HIER_DEMO VALUES (18, 'John', 17);
INSERT INTO HIER_DEMO VALUES (19, 'Frank', 18);
INSERT INTO HIER_DEMO VALUES (20, 'Tim', 19);
```

I am looking for the query that searches the tree for word 'Brian' in the `LABEL` column

The query should return these data

```
ID  LABEL   PARENT_ID
1   Mike    1
3   Alex    1
5   Brian   3
6   Rick    3
9   Tim 5
10  Andrew  5
12  Brian   6
```

Could somebody help with the Oracle query? We are using 11.2 version of Oracle database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SQL> select * from HIER_DEMO
  2  start with label like '%Brian%'
  3  connect by prior id = parent_id
  4  union
  5  select * from HIER_DEMO
  6  start with label like '%Brian%'
  7  connect by prior parent_id = id and PRIOR parent_id != PRIOR id
  8  /

  ID LABEL                PARENT_ID                                             
---- -------------------- ---------                                             
   1 Mike                         1                                             
   3 Alex                         1                                             
   5 Brian                        3                                             
   6 Rick                         3                                             
   9 Tim                          5                                             
  10 Andrew                       5                                             
  12 Brian                        6
```

Comment: Would not work for `'%Mike%'` instead of `'%Brian%'`

Comment: Egor, interesting. I have added nocycle and it is working now for 'Make' as well.

Answer (score 0):

We can use recursive CTE to accomplish this

```
WITH CTE1(ID, LABEL,PARENT_ID) AS
(
    SELECT * FROM Hier_Demo 
    WHERE LABEL LIKE '%Brian%' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT h.ID, h.LABEL, h.PARENT_ID FROM Hier_Demo h
    INNER JOIN CTE1 c
    ON h.ID = c.PARENT_ID
    WHERE h.ID <> h.PARENT_ID   
),
CTE2(ID, LABEL,PARENT_ID) AS
(
    SELECT * FROM Hier_Demo 
    WHERE LABEL LIKE '%Brian%' 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT h.ID, h.LABEL, h.PARENT_ID FROM Hier_Demo h
    INNER JOIN CTE2 c
    ON h.PARENT_ID = c.ID  
)
SELECT  * FROM CTE2
UNION 
SELECT  * FROM CTE1 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM HIER_DEMO WHERE ID = 1
```

In the above code CTE1 gets records up in the hierarchy and CTE2 gets records down in the hierarchy of Brian, after that we just `UNION` the records returned by these CTEs

see the code working at SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0c99d/39

Comment: I am working on a bug here, the record with ID = 1 is not showing up in the output

Comment: Added `SELECT * FROM HIER_DEMO WHERE ID = 1` after I couldn't figure out anything better

Comment: this tree will always return at least one record. whereas if it does not find anything it should not return anything. :)

Comment: No worries Dipendu, Dmitry has already provided correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

```
    SELECT * FROM HIER_DEMO WHERE PARENT_ID=
    (SELECT id FROM HIER_DEMO WHERE LABEL='Brian');
```

Comment: Sir, I appreciate quick reply. Would you mind first trying to run the query yourself first before posting it here? Thanks. I am sure that this is incorrect query. Thank though anyways.